# Is copy-constructor a viable overload?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
struct A {
  A(int){}
  A(A const &){}
};

int main() {
  A y(5);
}
```

The variable `y` is direct-initialized with the expression `5`.The overload resolution selects the constructor `A::A(int)`, which is what I expect and want, but why does it happen?

It may be so for two reasons:

either the overload `A::A(int)` is a better match then `A::A(A const &)`, or the second one is not a viable overload at all.

Question: In the above program, is the constructor `A::A(A const &)` a viable overload for initialization of `y`?

Comment: Turning the question around: What is making you suspect `A::A(A const&)` may not be a viable overload?

Comment: You can test that yourself by removing `A(int){}`. Also reference binding rules should be covered in your book.

Comment: [over.match.viable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match#viable)

Comment: @nwp: No, because doing that changes the viability of the copy constructor.  It *is* viable now, because the argument is convertable to a temporary A which `const A&` can bind.  If you remove the other constructor, the argument is no longer compatible with `const A&`.

Comment: Oh, I read that as `int` vs `const int &`. Ignore everything I said.

Comment: @Frank I was thinking of [over.best.ics/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.best.ics#4.3)

Comment: This will be an infinite recursion should the copy constructor be selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the rules for constructor overloading are same as for ordinary functions. The compiler is allowed to make one user-defined conversion *per parameter - as pointed by Ben Voigt -* in order to match the parameters with arguments. In this case it can do `int->A` through `A(5)`

This situation is the same as:

```
void foo(const std::string&);
void bar(const std::string&);//1
void bar(const char*);//2

//...
foo("Hello");//Is allowed
bar("Hello");//Calls 2 as it matches exactly without a need for conversion.
```

So, the answer, yes it's viable overload but it's not chosen because according to [overloading rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) the `A(int)` constructor is a better match.

Comment: There is no user defined conversion in the original code.

Comment: @nwp Since the `int` constructor is not explicit, it is a user defined conversion from an `int` to an `A` object. Which is perhaps what is confusing OP

Comment: Sorry, but this question is tagged language-lawyer. cppreference.com is far from normative.

Comment: The limit of "one user-defined conversion" applies *per parameter*

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, thank you I did not specify it as the OP's ctor has only one parameter. But added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[[class.conv.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#1):

> A constructor that is not explicit ([dcl.fct.spec]) specifies a
>   conversion from the types of its parameters (if any) to the type of
>   its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     X(int);
>     X(const char*, int =0);
>     X(int, int);
> };
>
> void f(X arg)
> {
>     X a = 1;          // a = X(1)
>     X b = "Jessie";   // b = X("Jessie",0)
>     a = 2;            // a = X(2)
>     f(3);             // f(X(3))
>     f({1, 2});        // f(X(1,2))
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

and

[[over.match.copy]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match#copy-1):

> Assuming that “cv1 T” is the type of the object being initialized, with T a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> (1.1) The converting constructors of T are candidate functions.